# Adding entry to end of line Ansible SLES 12

Tags: ansible

On SLES 12 server. Trying to append to this entry in my `/etc/security/pam_winbind.conf` file with this extra entry `S-1-5-21-84296906-944397292-530207130-587119`.

The line is

```bash
require_membership_of=S-1-5-21-84296906-944397292-530207130-496773,S-1-5-21-84296906-944397292-530207130-71056,S-1-5-21-84296906-944397292-530207130-218591
```

My playbook

```yaml
---
- name: Configuring ad_access_filter for RHEL systems.
  hosts: smt-test
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Taking Backup.
    copy:
      src: /etc/security/pam_winbind.conf
      dest: /etc/security/pam_winbind.conf.backup
      remote_src: yes

  - name: Add HQCloud to the sssd.conf file
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/security/pam_winbind.conf
      backrefs: yes
      regexp: '(^*2185915*)$'
      line: '\1,S-1-5-21-84296906-944397292-530207130-587119'

  - name: Add HQCloudScapeSupp to the sudoers file.
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/sudoers
      line: 'HQCloudScapeSupp ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'

  - name: Restarting WinBind Service
    service:
      name: winbind
      state: restarted
```

Since the `pam_winbind.conf` will be different on each server, how do I just add that entry to the end of that line regardless of the other memberships?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your approach IMO

1. It might be possible to do add your membership line with only a regex and backrefences but achieving idempotence will be a real pain. Indeed, you actually need to add your required membership if it does not already exist **anywhere in the string** (it might be present but not in last position). If it is already present anywhere, you should not touch anything.
2. You are making a backup of your file separately where the `lineinfile` module can do this automatically for you and only when there is a change
3. you are unconditionally restarting your service where it should only restart when something has actually changed requiring a restart.

The below playbook addresses the above issues:

```yaml
---
- name: Configuring ad_access_filter for RHEL systems.
  hosts: smt-test
  become: yes

  vars:
    config_file: /etc/security/pam_winbind.conf
    required_member: S-1-5-21-84296906-944397292-530207130-587119
    search_needle: require_membership_of=
    search_regexp: "^{{ search_needle }}(.*)$"


  tasks:
    - name: slurp file content to get existing membership entries
      slurp:
        path: "{{ config_file }}"
      register: slurped_file

    - name: Add HQCloud to the sssd.conf file if it does not exist + backup if any change
      vars:
        file_content_lines: "{{ (slurped_file.content | b64decode).splitlines() }}"
        requirement_line: "{{ file_content_lines | select('match', search_needle) | first }}"
        existing_members: "{{ (requirement_line | regex_replace(search_regexp, '\\g<1>')).split(',') | map('trim') }}"
        wanted_members: "{{ existing_members | union([required_member]) }}"
      lineinfile:
        path: "{{ config_file }}"
        regexp: "{{ search_regexp }}"
        backup: true
        line: "{{ search_needle }}{{ wanted_members | join(',') }}"

    - name: Add HQCloudScapeSupp to the sudoers file.
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/sudoers
        line: 'HQCloudScapeSupp ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
      # Not really sure this is needed
      notify: Restart winbind

  handlers:
    - name: Restart winbind
      service:
        name: winbind
        state: restarted
```

Comment: TASK [Add HQCloud to the sssd.conf file if it does not exist + backup if any change] *************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [smt-test]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ existing_members | union([required_member]) }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ existing_members | union([required_member]) }}): coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found"}

Comment: Not sure what this means since I'm new to Ansible